# How can I add up the values of the individual digits in a string?

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, cin, range-based-loop

I want to get the sum of the individual digits of an ID entered by the user. So far this is the code I have, and my code can count the number of characters in the user input but I'd like for it to also calculate the sum of the individual digits.

```
// user prompt for student id
cout << "Type in your student login ID: "; 

string studentId;

// user input of student ID
getline(cin, studentId); 

// computer output of studentId
cout << "Student ID Sum: " << studentId.length() << endl;
```

Comment: So you want to sum the individual digits? If the user entered `"456"` you want `15`? Or is the user entering different number separated by some delimiter, and you want to sum those?

Comment: Well, for that, you need to convert each character entered into an `int` and maintain a running sum.

Comment: @Chris Yes that is exactly what I'm trying to do. If input is 456 then output should be 15.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the range based for loop. As for example

```
unsigned int sum = 0;

for ( const auto &c : studentId )
{
    if ( '0' <= c && c <= '9' ) sum += c - '0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of `std::accumulate` from `<numeric>` for this purpose, iterating over the string `s` and adding the numeric value of each character to an accumulator if it's a digit.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
  std::string s = "456";

  std::cout << std::accumulate(
    s.begin(), s.end(), 0,
    [](unsigned int i, char &ch){ return std::isdigit(ch) ? i + (ch - '0') : i; }
  ) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
15
```

Answer (score 0):

> read string character by character in for loop and covert character to integer by adding it to the sum

```
int sum =0;
for (int i=0; i< studentId.length(); i++){
    sum = sum  +  ((int)studentId[i] - 48);
}
cout<<sum;
```

Comment: Why are you casting (and a C-style cast as well) `studentId[i]` to `int`?

Comment: because its a character if we directly add it. The ascii value will be considered.

Comment: What does `studentId[0] - '0'` give you?

Comment: it will give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do with the help of input and output formatting.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "2342";

    std::istringstream iss {s};
    std::ostringstream oss;

    // so that stream can look like : 2 3 4 2
    // adding whitespace after every number 
    for (char ch; iss >> ch;) {
        oss << ch << ' ';
    }

    std::string new_string = oss.str();
    std::istringstream new_iss {new_string};

    // read individual character of string as a integer using input      
    // formatting.
    int sum = 0;
    for (int n; new_iss >> n;) {
        sum += n;
    }

    std::cout << "sum :" << sum << '\n';
}
```